# Java JscrollPane

Tags: java

Hello I have a game where you can have a shop and buy stuff. when you press enter the shop stock menu opens. I want to be able to show all of the items available and I want to be able to scroll threw them all with a jscrollpane or jscrollbar. I don't know how I would approach this please help me and please don't take this question down mods and admins because tis will be very helpful for me. here is my code if you need to see it:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class stock {
    static Image img;
    public static int money = 1000;

    public static ArrayList<item> item = new ArrayList<item>();
    public static JScrollPane j = new JScrollPane();
    public static void tick(){
        if(Keys.isPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)){
            options.stockopen = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < item.toArray().length; i++) {
            item.get(i).tick();
        }

        item.add(new item(200,100,8,"Melon"));
        item.add(new item(200,150,2,"Bread"));
        item.add(new item(200,200,1,"Milk"));

    }

    public static void render(Graphics g){
        ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/stockscreen.png");
        img = i2.getImage();
        g.drawImage(img,0,0, null);


        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("€ "+money, 13, 30);

        for (int i = 0; i < item.toArray().length; i++) {
            item.get(i).render(g);
            //if (item.get(i).isrem) {

            //}
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Begging is not an effective way to avoid having your question closed.  Being specific and explaining what you have already tried is more effective.  I'm voting to close right now, because a blanket "please tell me how to do this" makes for a bad question.  If you can, edit your question to ask about a specific problem you have had implementing your scroll area.  In the meantime: https://www.google.com/search?q=javax.swing.jscrollpane+example

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the menu container into the `JscrollPane` when `new JscrollPane(menuContainer)` and add the `JscrollPane` object you create where you are adding your menu-container.

**example**
If you want a `JPanel` to be in a `JFrame` and have `JScrollPane` to scroll through, you can do so by.....

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
// some statements
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
// some statements
JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(jp);
jf.add(jp);
```

something like this.. here jp will be like the menu-container.

Comment: I don't fully understand that

Comment: what is a menu container

Comment: You must be having something to Contain your menus, that would be your menu container, its a term not an actual part.